# How to return different result in the same query?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, null

I'm trying to return different result in one query, in particular the query return the `ranking` of a particular `competition`  using `round.id` field, now sometimes this table can have the field `group.id` valorized, if so I need to return only the ranking which have as `group.id` the minimum value available, so I create this design:

```
SELECT l.*,
t.name as team_name,
r.name AS rank_name,
r.color AS rank_color
FROM league_ranking l
LEFT JOIN team t ON l.team_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN competition_ranks r ON l.rank = r.id
INNER JOIN competition_groups g 
WHERE l.round_id = :round_id
AND l.group_id = (
  SELECT MIN(l2.group_id)
  FROM league_ranking l2
  WHERE l2.round_id = :round_id
)
```

this working if the ranking records have the `group.id` available, but if this field is `NULL` nothing will be returned, a little example of `league_ranking` table data:

```
| round_id | group_id | team_id
     5         3         1045
     5         3         1046
     6         NULL      1047
     6         NULL      1048
```

if I search as `round.id` 5, will be returned the first two records, but if instead I search for `round.id` 6, nothing will be returned. How can I structure my query to return the result also if there is no `group.id` associated?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`null` isn't a value, it's the lackthereof. `null = null` returns `null`, not `true`, so for groups without an id, this query won't work.

You can use the `<=>` instead of `=`, though, to evaluate two `null`s as being equal:

```
SELECT l.*,
t.name as team_name,
r.name AS rank_name,
r.color AS rank_color
FROM league_ranking l
LEFT JOIN team t ON l.team_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN competition_ranks r ON l.rank = r.id
INNER JOIN competition_groups g 
WHERE l.round_id = :round_id
AND l.group_id <=> ( -- <=> used here instead of =
  SELECT MIN(l2.group_id)
  FROM league_ranking l2
  WHERE l2.round_id = :round_id
)
```